# Use Adobe reader instead of chrome pdf viewer to display a pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdftk, adobe-reader

I'm outputting a pdf which has been made with scribus, and in all browsers except for chrome it outputs fine, however with chrome the letters are cut off and lower than usual. I found that disabling the chrome pdf viewer fixes the issue locally. But what about users who do not have it disabled? Is there some way I can make adobe reader show it instead of the chrome pdf viewer in my code?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

**Edit:** I can't make the user download the pdf as it is somewhat a preview before they send it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up flattening the pdf using the flatten option, it unified the result accross all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a Content-Disposition header to force the PDF to download as an attachment.  When the user clicked on the downloaded file, it would then open in their registered PDF viewer rather than in Chrome.

Comment: Indeed that is a solution but we just switched to inline from attachment...It's a preview sortof so it gotta open as a new tab..

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to force Chrome to display it in Acrobat.  You could make this behaviour Chrome-specific and display it inline in other browsers.  Other than that, I'd suggest looking at why the PDF renders differently and raise a bug with Scribus or Chromium, whichever is at fault.

Comment: It has to be chrome as all the other major browsers display the pdf correctly unfortunatly